# This code runs perfectly but I wonder what the parameter 'x' in my_forward function refers to

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, attention-model, self-attention, vision-transformer

refering to the attention maps in VIT transformers example in: https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/discussions/1232?sort=old

This code runs perfectly but I wonder what the parameter 'x' in my_forward function refers to. and How and where in the code the x value is passed to the function my_forward.

```
def my_forward(x):
        B, N, C = x.shape

        qkv = attn_obj.qkv(x).reshape(
            B, N, 3, attn_obj.num_heads, C // attn_obj.num_heads).permute(2, 0, 3, 1, 4)
        # make torchscript happy (cannot use tensor as tuple)
        q, k, v = qkv.unbind(0)
```

Comment: If you want to ask about code you need to post the code here, not link to another site. I notice that you've already posted a question on GitHub, so why not give the code author time to answer before posting badly constructed questions here? See [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a little code inspection but you can easily find the implementation if you look in the right places. Let us start with your snippet.

- The `my_forward_wrapper` function is a function generator that defines `my_forward` and returns it. This implementation is overwriting the implementation of the last block attention layer `blocks[-1].attn` of the loaded model `"deit_small_distilled_patch16_224"`.

  ```
  model.blocks[-1].attn.forward = my_forward_wrapper(model.blocks[-1].attn)
  ```
- What the `x` corresponds to is the output of the previous block. To understand, you can dive into the source code of [timm](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/deit.py). The model loaded in the script is [`deit_small_distilled_patch16_224`](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/deit.py#L295-L302) which returns a [`VisionTransformerDistilled`](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/deit.py#L29) instance. The blocks are defined in the [`VisionTransformer`](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/vision_transformer.py#L507-521) class. There are `n=depth` blocks defined sequentially. The default block definition is given by [`Block`](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/vision_transformer.py#L123) in which attn is implemented by [`Attention`](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/vision_transformer.py#L57), the details are given here:

  ```
  def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
      B, N, C = x.shape
      qkv = self.qkv(x) \
                .reshape(B, N, 3, self.num_heads, self.head_dim) \
                .permute(2, 0, 3, 1, 4)
      q, k, v = qkv.unbind(0)
      q, k = self.q_norm(q), self.k_norm(k)

      if self.fused_attn:
          x = F.scaled_dot_product_attention(
              q, k, v,
              dropout_p=self.attn_drop.p if self.training else 0.,
          )
      else:
          q = q * self.scale
          attn = q @ k.transpose(-2, -1)
          attn = attn.softmax(dim=-1)
          attn = self.attn_drop(attn)
          x = attn @ v

      x = x.transpose(1, 2).reshape(B, N, C)
      x = self.proj(x)
      x = self.proj_drop(x)
      return x
  ```

  While the implementation - that you provided - overwriting it is:

  ```
  def my_forward(x):
      B, N, C = x.shape
      qkv = attn_obj.qkv(x) \
              .reshape(B, N, 3, attn_obj.num_heads, C // attn_obj.num_heads) \
              .permute(2, 0, 3, 1, 4)
      q, k, v = qkv.unbind(0)

      attn = (q @ k.transpose(-2, -1)) * attn_obj.scale
      attn = attn.softmax(dim=-1)
      attn = attn_obj.attn_drop(attn)
      attn_obj.attn_map = attn
      attn_obj.cls_attn_map = attn[:, :, 0, 2:]

      x = (attn @ v).transpose(1, 2).reshape(B, N, C)
      x = attn_obj.proj(x)
      x = attn_obj.proj_drop(x)
      return x
  ```

  The idea is that the attention map is being cached as an attribute to the attention layer with `attn_obj.attn_map = attn`, such that it can be inspected after inference.